# div cannot be the same width as screen, another div does not allow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the red `div` be the same width with the screen. But it aligns to another `div`, it cannot be full width.

The area of red `div` is available until the green `div`, but I want it to be full width.

Also, I want the red `div` to be vertically and horizontally centered.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-12 mt-2" style="border-radius: 12px; height: 250px; background-color: #5b6269">


  <div class="position-fixed-top border bg-info float-right"
  style="
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    ">
      ئـۆفـه‌ری رۆژانــه‌
  </div>


  <div class="h-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12" style="background:red">
      Content content content content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used float-right class on the header which is making the below div not float to entire width adding an empty div with class="clearfix" is going to solve your issue.

here is a pen for the resolution.
https://codepen.io/mohammad-aslam/pen/axBxPP

```
<div class="col-12 mt-2" style="border-radius: 12px; height: 250px; background-color: #5b6269">


        <div class="position-fixed-top border bg-info float-right" style=" border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; font-size: 30px;background-color: green;">ئـۆفـه‌ری رۆژانــه‌
        </div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="h-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12" style="background:red">
                Content content content content
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To make red div in `middle vertically and make width:100%;` , You can set `position:absolute; to upper div`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-12 mt-2" style="border-radius: 12px; height: 250px; background-color: #5b6269">

  <div class="position-fixed-top border bg-info"
    style="
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
      background-color: green;
      position:absolute;
      right:15px;
      top:0px;
      ">
    ئـۆفـه‌ری رۆژانــه‌
  </div>

  <div class="h-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="col-12" 
    style="
    background:red;
    ">
      Content content content content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the div occupy any space of the document flow, you'd better use `position: absolute` for it:

```
<div 
    class="position-fixed-top position-absolute border bg-info float-right" 
    style="
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
        background-color: green;
    ">
    ئـۆفـه‌ری رۆژانــه‌
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/busuxufozo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

you can add container-fluid class and give absolute position as shown.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-12 mt-2" style="border-radius: 12px; height: 250px; background-color: #5b6269">


        <div class="position-fixed-top border bg-info float-right" style=" border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; font-size: 30px;background-color: green;">ئـۆفـه‌ری رۆژانــه‌
        </div>


        <div class="h-100 row align-items-center justify-content-center container-fluid" style="position: absolute;">
            <div class="col-12" style="background:red">
                Content content content content
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

only change (position-fixed-top) to ( position-fixed-top position-absolute)